# Integers $p,q$ such that $pq\equiv 1 \mod (p+q) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find pair of integers $p,q$ of the form:
$$pq\equiv 1 \mod (p+q) $$

What have I tried so far is:

Since, $pq \equiv 1 \implies p$ has inverse element with respect to $p+q$. which means $$gcd( p+q, p)=1$$

Hence, both $p$ and $q$ can't be even numbers. Generalizing this condition gives:
$$gcd(p,q)=1$$

Now, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $$ pq = n(p+q) + 1.$$

This gives us $$ (p-n)(q-n) = n^2 + 1.$$

So, given any $n$, look at factorizations of $ n^2 + 1 = PQ$, and create $p = P+n$, $q = Q+n$.

---

As an explicit example, for $n=7$, we have $7^2 + 1 = 50 = 5 \times 10$, which gives us $p = 12, q = 17$. You can verify that

$$ 12 \times 17 \equiv 1 \pmod{29}$$